# CSS grid not showing right in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I have a CSS grid to display a portfolio. It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but not the latest Internet Explorer.

Here's what it supposed to look like in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge:
[image]

This is what's happening in IE 10 and 11 (does not show at all in 9 or lower):
[image]

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: ( minmax(300px, 1fr))[4];
    -ms-grid-rows: 250px;

}

.wrapper .box {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-row: auto;
}
```